# Need to encode repetitive pattern in String with * , such that * means "repeat from beginning"

Tags: java

Encoding format: introduce * to indicate "repeat from beginning".  Example. Input-{a,b,a,b,c,a,b,a,b,c,d} can be written as {a , b, * ,c, * , d}. Output:5; E.g 2:  ABCABCE, output- 5.

Here * means repeat from beginning. For example if given String is ABCABCABCABC , it will return ABC**, another example is if String is ABCABCABC, it will return ABC*ABC.

I have the below code but this code assumes that the string will contain the repetitive pattern only and no other characters, I want to modify it to check :
1. Which pattern is repeating
2. Ignore non repeating patterns
2. encode that pattern according to the problem statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Magicpotion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string:");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int len = str.length();
        if (len != 0) {
            int lenby3 = len / 3;
            int starcount = ( int).(Math.log(lenby3) / Math.log(2));
            int leftstring = (lenby3 - (int) Math.pow(2, starcount));
            int resultlen = (1 * 3) + starcount + (leftstring * 3);
            System.out.println("ResultLength: " + resultlen);
            System.out.print("ABC");
            for (int i = 0; i < starcount; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < leftstring; i++) {
                System.out.print("ABC");
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("ResultLength: " + 0);
    }
}
```

Here my assumption is that ABC will always be repeating pattern , hence I have divided the length by 3. I want to generalise it such that I find the repeating pattern which can be a AB or BC or ABCD and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like homework. So instead of a full solution just some hints:

You can process the input string character by character and encode as you go. If you have at some point already read `k` characters and the next `k` characters are exactly the same, output a `*` and advance to position `2k`.
Otherwise, output the next input character and advance position to `k+1`.

As mentioned by dyukha this algorithm does not always result in the shortest possible encoding. If this is required some more effort has to be put into the search.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using dynamic programming.
Assume that you processed your stay at some position `i`. You want to understand what it the minimal length of encoding of `str[0..i]`. Let's call it `ans[i]`. You have two options:

- Just add `i`-th character to the encoding. So the length is `ans[i-1] + 1`.
- You may write `*`, when possible. In this case the length is `ans[i / 2] + 1` or something like this.

The final length is in `ans[n-1]`. You can store how you obtained `ans[i]` to recover the encoding itself.
Checking whether you can write `*` can be optimized, using some hashing (to obtain `O(n)` solution instead of `O(n^2)`).

The difference with Henry's solution is that he always applies `*` when it's possible. It's not clear to me that it results into the minimal length (if I understood correctly, `aaaaaa` is a counterexample), so I'm giving a solution I'm sure about.

Answer (score 0):

```java
/**
 * @author mohamed ali
 * https://www.linkedin.com/in/oo0shaheen0oo/
 */

public class Magic_potion_encoding
{
    private static int minimalSteps( String ingredients )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ingredients);

        for(int i =0;i<sb.length();i++)
        {
            char startChar = sb.charAt(i);
            int walkingIndex1=i;
            int startIndex2 =sb.toString().indexOf(startChar,i+1);
            int  walkingIndex2=startIndex2;
            while(walkingIndex2 !=-1 && walkingIndex2<sb.length() && sb.charAt(walkingIndex1) == sb.charAt(walkingIndex2)  )
            {
                if(walkingIndex1+1==startIndex2)
                {
                   String subStringToBeEncoded = sb.substring(i,walkingIndex2+1);//substring the string found and the original "substring does not include the last index hence the +1
                   int matchStartIndex = sb.indexOf(subStringToBeEncoded,walkingIndex2+1);// look for first match for the whole string matched
                   int matchEndeIndex= matchStartIndex+subStringToBeEncoded.length();
                   int origStartIndex=i;
                   int origEndIndex = i+subStringToBeEncoded.length();
                   if (matchStartIndex!=-1 )
                   {
                       if(origEndIndex==matchStartIndex)
                       {
                           sb.replace(matchStartIndex,matchEndeIndex,"*");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           while(matchStartIndex!=-1 && matchEndeIndex<sb.length() && sb.charAt(origEndIndex) == sb.charAt(matchEndeIndex)  )
                           {
                               if(origEndIndex==matchStartIndex-1)// if the index of the 2 strings are right behind one another
                               {
                                   sb.replace(matchStartIndex,matchEndeIndex+1,"*");
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   origEndIndex++;
                                   matchEndeIndex++;
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   sb.replace(startIndex2,walkingIndex2+1,"*");
                   break;
                }
                walkingIndex1++;
                walkingIndex2++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("orig= " + ingredients + " encoded = " + sb);
        return sb.length();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        if (    minimalSteps("ABCABCE") == 5 &&
                minimalSteps("ABCABCEA") == 6 &&
                minimalSteps("abbbbabbbb") == 5 &&
                minimalSteps("abcde") == 5 &&
                minimalSteps("abcbcbcbcd") == 6 &&
                minimalSteps("ababcababce") == 6 &&
                minimalSteps("ababababxx") == 6 &&
                minimalSteps("aabbccbbccaabbccbbcc") == 8)
        {
            System.out.println( "Pass" );
        }
  else
        {
            System.out.println( "Fail" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: answers without explanations are marked as low quality... can you provide some explanation with this code for better context and understanding

Answer (score 0):

Given that the repetitions are from the beginning, every such repeating substring will have the very first character of the given string. [Every repetition needs to be represented by a "star". (i.e ABCABCABC ans = ABC** ) . If all sequential repetitions are to be represented with one "star". (i.e ABCABCABC and = ABC* ), a slight modification to (2) will do the thing (i.e remove the if case where the just a star is added)]

1. Divide the given string to substrings based on the first character.

   Eg. Given String = "ABABCABD"
   Sub Strings = {"AB", "ABC", "AB", "ABD"}
2. Just traverse through the list of substrings and get the required result. I've used a map here, to make the search easy.

Just a rough write up.

```
SS = {"AB", "ABC", "AB", "ABD"};
result = SS[0];
Map<string, bool> map;
map.put(SS[0],true);
for (i = 1; i < SS.length; i++){
    if (map.hasKey(SS[i])){
        result += "*";          
    }
    else {
        res = nonRepeatingPart(SS[i], map);
        result += "*" + res;
        map.put(SS[i], true);
    }
}

String nonRepeatingPart(str, map){
    for (j = str.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
        if (map.hasKey(str.subString(0, j))){
            return str.subString(j, str.length-1);
        }
    }
    return throwException("Wrong Input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string getCompressed(string str){
    string res;
    res += str[0];
    int i=1;
    while(i<str.size()){
           //check if current char is the first char in res
        char curr = str[i];
        if(res[0]==curr){
            if(str.substr(0,i)==str.substr(i,i)){
                res += '*';
                i+=i; continue;
            }else{
                res += curr;
                i++; continue;
            }
        }else {
            res += curr;
            i++; continue;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
int main()
{
   string s = "ABCABCABC";
   string res = getCompressed(s);
   cout<<res.size();
   
   return 0;
}
```